# Cohomology ring of $H^*(\mathbb{R}P^{\infty} \times \mathbb{R}P^{\infty}; \mathbb{Z})$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

This is course work

> Prove that the cohomology ring $H^*(\mathbb{R}P^{\infty} \times \mathbb{R}P^{\infty}; \mathbb{Z})$ is isomorphic to the subring of $\mathbb{Z}[x, y]/(2x, 2y)$ generated by $x^2, y^2, xy^2 + x^2y$ with $x$ and $y$ in degree $1$.
>
> Hint: Use the Bockstein cohomology to show that every element of $\tilde{H}^*(\mathbb{R}P^\infty \times \mathbb{R}P^\infty; \mathbb{Z})$ is of order $2$.

I think the reduced Bockstein cohomology is trivial, but have trouble showing it.

We have a projection $\pi: \mathbb{R}P^\infty \times \mathbb{R}P^\infty \to \mathbb{R}P^\infty$ with a section $x \mapsto (x, y_0)$ where $y_0$ is the zero-cell of $\mathbb{R}P^\infty$. So the induced homomorphism is split mono, hence injective. Using naturality to obtain a diagram

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
H^n(\mathbb{R}P^\infty; \mathbb{Z}/2) @>{\beta'}>> H^{n+1}(\mathbb{R}P^\infty; \mathbb{Z}/2)\\
@V{\pi^*}VV @V{\pi^*}VV\\
H^{n}(\mathbb{R}P^\infty \times \mathbb{R}P^\infty; \mathbb{Z}/2) @>{\beta}>> H^{n+1}(\mathbb{R}P^\infty \times \mathbb{R}P^\infty; \mathbb{Z}/2)
\end{CD}

where $\beta$ and $\beta'$ are Bocksteins. It is known that $\beta'$ is an isomorphism for $n$ odd, as $\pi^*$ is injective, we see that the kernel of $\beta$ is contained in the image of $\pi^*$ (the left one). For $n$ even, it is known that $\beta'$ is $0$. Taking the naturality square for $i^*$ we see that $i^* \circ \beta$ is the zero map. So the image of $\beta$ is contained in the kernel of $i^*$ (the left one). Here I am stuck.

Suppose that the Bockstein cohomology is trivial. We can write any abelian group/$\mathbb{Z}$-module as a direct sum of copies of $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/p^k$ for $p$ prime, and know that postcomposition with $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/p$ sends summands $\mathbb{Z}$ in $H^n(X; \mathbb{Z}$ to a summand $\mathbb{Z}/p$ in $BH_p^n(X)$, a summand $\mathbb{Z}/p^k$ in $H^n(X, \mathbb{Z})$ to a summand $\mathbb{Z}/p$ in $BH_p^n(X)$ for $k > 1$. If the Bokstein cohomology is trivial, then $H^*(\mathbb{R}P^\infty \times \mathbb{R}P^\infty; \mathbb{Z})$ must consist out of copies of $\mathbb{Z}/2$, which proves the statement of the hint.

We have calculated before that $H^*(\mathbb{R}P^\infty; \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}[x]/(2x)$, so the projections induce injections $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(2x), \mathbb{Z}[y]/(2y)$ into $H^*(\mathbb{R}P^\infty \times \mathbb{R}P^\infty; \mathbb{Z})$. I don't know how to continue.

Comment: I don't see why $\pi^*$ is increasing the degree

Comment: @William It's not, my bad

Comment: Don't you know the Künneth formula ?

Comment: (By the way, The cohomological Bockstein is *not* $0$. For instance if you know that $H^*(\mathbb RP^\infty, \mathbb Z/2) = \mathbb Z/2 [x]$, $x$ in degree $1$, you can check that $\beta x = x^2$, so that this also holds (by naturality) in $H^*(\mathbb RP^\infty\times \mathbb RP^\infty,\mathbb Z/2) = \mathbb Z/2 [x,y]$. In fact, $\beta  = Sq^1$, the first Steenrod square, so it's just the square on degree $1$ elements (the rest of the Bockstein can be determined by the fact that it's a derivation). )

Comment: @Max yes, how do we use it? As $\mathbb{R}P^\infty$ does not have free cohomology groups, we don't have a ring isomorphism $H^*(\mathbb{R}P^\infty \times \mathbb{R}P^\infty) \cong H^*(\mathbb{R}P^\infty) \times H^*(\mathbb{R}P^\infty)$.

Comment: @Max The Bockstein cohomology is defined as the the cohomology of the sequence $H^0(X) \xrightarrow{\beta} H^1(X) \xrightarrow{\beta} H^2(X) \xrightarrow{\beta} ...$ in my course. Is that what you mean as well?

Comment: Ah I thought you meant the Bockstein morphism ! Well then you can explicit the Bockstein morphism and check that it is exact

Comment: As for Künneth, you can nonetheless use it to prove that every element has order $2$